# Changing in the Quantity of variants reflecting in the wrong item in Order Summary

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a problem with the variations and the quantity related to it in the order summary page.

It was working perfectly and all of a sudden (this is an example to simplify):

when I add to the cart 2 items:

- Item X with a size small
- Item X with a size medium

When I change the quantity of item X size medium, this change is reflecting in item X size small which was chosen first.

In the order summary, there are a plus and minus in the template to change the quantity.

I have identified the problem but I can't figure out why it is occurring

Here is the template:

```
{% block content %}
    <main>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap" style="margin-top:90px">
        <h2> Order Summary</h2>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Item Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Price</th>
                <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                <th scope="col">Size</th> 
                <th scope="col">Total Item Price</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for order_item in object.items.all %}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                <td>{{ order_item.item.title }}</td>
                <td>{{ order_item.item.price }}</td>
                <td>
                <a href="{% url 'core:remove-single-item-from-cart' order_item.item.slug %}"><i class="fas fa-minus mr-2"></a></i>
                {{ order_item.quantity }}
                <a href="{% url 'core:add-to-cart' order_item.item.slug %}"><i class="fas fa-plus ml-2"></a></i>
                </td>                
                <td>
                {% if order_item.variation.all %}
                {% for variation in order_item.variation.all %}
                {{ variation.title|capfirst }}
                {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                </td> 
                <td>
                {% if order_item.item.discount_price %}
                    $ {{ order_item.get_total_discount_item_price }}
                    <span class="badge badge-primary" style="margin-left:10px">Saving ${{ order_item.get_amount_saved }}</span>
                {% else %}
                    $ {{ order_item.get_total_item_price }}
                {% endif %}
                <a style="color:red" href="{% url 'core:remove-from-cart' order_item.item.slug %}">
                <i class="fas fa-trash float-right"></i>
                </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% empty %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan='5'>Your Cart is Empty</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                <a class='btn btn-primary float-right ml-2'href='/'>Continue Shopping</a>
            </tr>                
            {% endfor %}
            {% if object.coupon %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><b>Coupon</b></td>
                <td><b>-${{ object.coupon.amount }}</b></td>
            </tr>            
            {% endif %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"><b>Sub total</b></td>
                <td><b>${{ object.get_total }}</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">Taxes</td>
                <td>${{ object.get_taxes|floatformat:2  }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% if object.grand_total %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"><b>Grand Total</b></td>
                <td><b>${{ object.grand_total|floatformat:2 }}</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">
                <a class='btn btn-primary float-right ml-2'href='/'>Continue Shopping</a>
                <a class='btn btn-warning float-right'href='/checkout/'>Proceed to Checkout</a></td>
            </tr> 
            {% endif %}                          
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <!--Main layout-->
{% endblock content %}
```

Here is the views.py

```
class OrderSummaryView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            context = {
                'object': order
            }
            return render(self.request, 'order_summary.html', context)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("/")


@login_required
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)

    order_item_qs = OrderItem.objects.filter(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )

    item_var = []  # item variation
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for items in request.POST:
            key = items
            val = request.POST[key]
            try:
                v = Variation.objects.get(
                    item=item,
                    category__iexact=key,
                    title__iexact=val
                )
                item_var.append(v)
            except:
                pass

        if len(item_var) > 0:
            for items in item_var:
                order_item_qs = order_item_qs.filter(
                    variation__exact=items,
                )

    if order_item_qs.exists():
        order_item = order_item_qs.first()
        order_item.quantity += 1
        order_item.save()
    else:
        order_item = OrderItem.objects.create(
            item=item,
            user=request.user,
            ordered=False
        )
        order_item.variation.add(*item_var)
        order_item.save()

    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if not order.items.filter(item__id=order_item.id).exists():
            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated.")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(
            user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        messages.info(request, "This item was added to cart.")
        return redirect("core:order-summary")


@login_required
def remove_from_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(
                item=item,
                user=request.user,
                ordered=False
            )[0]
            order.items.remove(order_item)
            order_item.delete()
            messages.info(request, "This item was removed from your cart")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")

        else:
            messages.info(request, "This item was not in your cart")
            return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)
    else:
        messages.info(request, "You don't have an active order")
        return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)


@login_required
def remove_single_item_from_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(
                item=item,
                user=request.user,
                ordered=False
            )[0]
            if order_item.quantity > 1:
                order_item.quantity -= 1
                order_item.save()
            else:
                order.items.remove(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")
        else:
            messages.info(request, "This item was not in your cart")
            return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)
    else:
        messages.info(request, "You do not have an active order")
        return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)
# End Remove Items (Products removed from Cart)
```

here is the models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title             = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    updated           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active            = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("core:product", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("core:add-to-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def get_remove_from_cart_url(self):
        return reverse("core:remove-from-cart", kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })


class VariationManager(models.Manager):
    def all(self):
        return super(VariationManager, self).filter(active=True)

    def sizes(self):
        return self.all().filter(category='size')

    def colors(self):
        return self.all().filter(category='color')


VAR_CATEGORIES = (
    ('size', 'size',),
    ('color', 'color',),
    ('package', 'package'),
)


class Variation(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=120, choices=VAR_CATEGORIES, default='size')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = VariationManager()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    variation = models.ManyToManyField(Variation)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.title}"
```

Comment: This is far too trimmed. We can't run this cause half the code is missing and what's left isn't a [Minimally Working Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example). From first glance, there's no way for add to cart to be called using a POST method, so the code never hits. How you're transmitting the selected variation is crucial here.

Comment: @Melvyn thank you I am sure you are correct as there are no feedbacks, what should I add to the question to make it clear, I am still new to this.

Comment: How does a user change the cart quantity?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica in the template there is a url to add-to-cart and remove-single-item-from-cart which is defined in the views

Comment: It would seem to be a simple bug in your code. It's not possible to pin point from the code you have posted but either the object reference being passed is always the first item in the list or the remote update logic is ignoring the refernce being passed and is always updating the first item in the list. Try adding different combinations of objects and then see if the update always changes the first item added no matter what it is. If that is the case then you can debug and see what in the code is always passing a reference to the first object or updating the first object no matter what.

Comment: "in the template there is a url to add-to-cart", but urls are transmitted by GET, so the code after `if request.method == 'POST':` never hits. Further more, even if it would, the add_to_cart url knows nothing about variations cause it only gets item slugs. What I suspect is that in the template from which we see only a snippet, there is also a `<form method="POST">` and that has the variants.

Comment: @Melvyn I have added the complete template in the question

Comment: There's no form in there. Where is the code that sends a POST request with form data to the add to cart view? If there is no such code, then you have your answer, because `item_var` will always be an empty list so `order_item.variation.add(*item_var)` does nothing.

Comment: @Melvyn I have tried to fix it but it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked your code. In your code, you are fetching items and then changing the quantity. Item X with larger size and Item X with a smaller size, I feel both are representing the same item. So changing in 1 item will reflect in same item with different sizes. Do you have any way to identify an item based on item_id as well as size?

```
OrderItem.objects.filter(
                item=item,
                user=request.user,
                ordered=False
            )[0].
```

to something like

```
OrderItem.objects.filter(
                item=item,
                user=request.user,
                size=item.size
                ordered=False
            )[0].
```

Something like adding size = S or L, Will make a difference. Additionally you are taking 1st element(using the array[0]). If there are two items with same data you might be doing the operation or wrong item. Instead of filter you can use get, If items are unique.

Comment: How can I set the changes to be based on the orderitem.id ?

Comment: In the variation table, you have a category and item table as a foreign key of variation. So you can fetch category also with item details.  After fetching category check for color, size, etc, and then get the exact item with the help of category. Ex:- So x-> Small size, quantity = 10.  So x-> Large size, quantity = 20.  After you fetch the item you have to check for the size then reduce the quantity. By looking at model files you can fetch these details from the variation table.